# .addClass is not adding class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // ADD CLASS ON LOAD FUNCTION SHOULD WORK HERE

    (function(){
      $('.block-layered-nav dt').addClass('closed');
    });

    $(".block-layered-nav dt").click(function(){
        if($(this).next("dd").css("display") == "none"){
            $(this).next("dd").slideDown(200);
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
        } else {
            $(this).next("dd").slideUp(200);
            $(this).addClass("closed");
        }
    });
});
```

Can anybody notice any visible issues with this?

The first function should add the class 'closed' to the `dt` element, however this is not the case when the page loads.

The other code is just to simply toggle the class and this is working fine.

Comment: Try calling your function ... like adding `()` after the 4th line. Or just take the 3rd line out of it

Comment: Why not to add class as attribute to html? class="closed"

Answer (score 6):

You're only defining an anonymous function, but never calling it:

```
(function(){
    $('.block-layered-nav dt').addClass('closed');
});
```

Simply change the above to this:

```
$('.block-layered-nav dt').addClass('closed');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply write

```
$('.block-layered-nav dt').addClass('closed');
```

to add the class? Why the self contained function (not called by the way)